# Why doesn't background-image work in an animation (in IE & Firefox)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, animation, background-image

This is my code, but in IE and Firefox it stays the image it was in the normal css. It is actually working in Chrome, Opera and also in Safari.

It flies from left to right and then from right ro left (so it is mirrored).

```
.plane {
    width:170px;
    height:85px;
    background-image:url(../images/plane.png);
    background-size:cover;
    margin-left:-100px;
    top:15px;
    animation: plane 24s 1;
    -webkit-animation: plane 24s 1;
    -o-animation: plane 24s 1;
    -moz-animation: plane 24s 1;
    -ms-animation: plane 24s 1;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -ms-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -o-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-delay:0s;
    cursor:pointer;
    z-index:1;
    position:absolute;
}

    @-ms-keyframes plane {
        0% {-ms-transform: translate(0px,0px); background-image:url(../images/plane.png);}
        5% {-ms-transform: translate(70px,7px); background-image:url(../images/plane2.png);} 
        10% {-ms-transform: translate(140px,1px); background-image:url(../images/plane3.png);} 
        15% {-ms-transform: translate(210px,7px); background-image:url(../images/plane.png);}
        20% {-ms-transform: translate(280px,1px); background-image:url(../images/plane2.png);}
        25% {-ms-transform: translate(350px,9px); background-image:url(../images/plane3.png);}
        30% {-ms-transform: translate(420px,1px); background-image:url(../images/plane.png);}
        35% {-ms-transform: translate(490px,7px); background-image:url(../images/plane2.png);}
        40% {-ms-transform: translate(560px,1px); background-image:url(../images/plane3.png);}
        45% {-ms-transform: translate(630px,7px); background-image:url(../images/plane.png);}
        50% {-ms-transform: translate(700px,1px); background-image:url(../images/plane2.png);}
        51% {-ms-transform: translate(700px,7px); background-image:url(../images/planeTurn.png);}
        55% {-ms-transform: translate(630px,1px); background-image:url(../images/plane2Turn.png);}
        60% {-ms-transform: translate(560px,7px); background-image:url(../images/plane3Turn.png);}
        65% {-ms-transform: translate(490px,1px); background-image:url(../images/planeTurn.png);} 
        70% {-ms-transform: translate(420px,9px); background-image:url(../images/plane2Turn.png);} 
        75% {-ms-transform: translate(350px,1px); background-image:url(../images/plane3Turn.png);} 
        80% {-ms-transform: translate(280px,5px); background-image:url(../images/planeTurn.png);} 
        85% {-ms-transform: translate(210px,1px); background-image:url(../images/plane2Turn.png);} 
        90% {-ms-transform: translate(140px,7px); background-image:url(../images/plane3Turn.png);} 
        95% {-ms-transform: translate(70px,1px); background-image:url(../images/planeTurn.png);} 
        100% {-ms-transform: translate(-75px,9px); background-image:url(../images/planeTurn.png);} 
}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: If you could give a fiddle reproducing your problem, I think it'll be easier to understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Whats is the "1" in this definition? `animation: plane 24s 1;`

Comment: http://yarondassoneville.be/webanimatie/doodle @EvertonLenger

Comment: Your link doesn't work.. Please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) about how to create a good example.

Comment: Oh sorry this will work. Made a mistake http://yarondassonneville.be/webanimatie/doodle @EvertonLenger